# Backbone: 'keypress' event handler depends on div's tabindex?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view that wraps Bootstrap's modal. On that view I'm trying to make the Esc key dismiss the modal, but whether it works or not, seems to depend on the existence of `<div>`'s `tabindex` attribute:

```js
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#modalOverlay', // is an existing container for modals

    events: {
        'keypress': function(event) { ... }
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        // the view pattern
        this.compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(yesNoQuestionAlertTemplate);
        this.options = options;
        this.render(options);
    },
});
```

The `yesNoQuestionAlertTemplate` contains the `tabindex` attribute, which sort of defines the correct handling of the escape key. When I remove the attribute, escape does not work, when I put it back, the handler gets triggered correctly.

```html
<div id="yesNoQuestion" class="modal large" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
     <!-- modal definition -->
</div>
```

Why does this strange dependency exist?

Comment: As per [docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), `keyboard` in Options section, shouldn't the modal automatically close on escape unless its explicitly specified not to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target of `keypress` event can be only the element that can have a focus. Input elements can have focus by default. To make any other HTML element to have a focus you need to assign a `tabindex` attribute to it.

When an element gets a focus the event bubbles up the DOM and is triggered on all parent elements. So you have to options:

- you should assign `tabindex` attribute to the element.
- catch the event on `body` or `window` because they are parents for all elements.